# Getting "undeclared identifier DBVERSION_80" when installing pymssql using pip

Tags: python, mysql, macos, pymssql

When  I install **pymssql** on my mac with 'pip install pymssql' it fails with `undeclared identifier DBVERSION_80`.

What's wrong?[image]

Comment: please provide code not as image but as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
brew install freetds
```

Source: http://pymssql.org/en/latest/intro.html

If you get this error:

```
__pyx_r = DBVERSION_80;
              ^
1 error generated.
```

then you can fix it with this:

```
brew unlink freetds
brew install homebrew/versions/freetds091
```

and then install:

```
pip install pymssql
```

source: https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/432

Comment: is it same as ```pip install pymssql```

Comment: @DyMu made some change. I tried it and it worked for me. Earlier I was getting the same error that you are getting.